# JS Module Pattern: How to initialize a local object

Tags: javascript

I'm confused about how to initialize a local object in a JS Module implementation. I have a local variable (an object) that I try and access in the object literal I return; however, when I try to add a new property to that object it says it's undefined. But if I don't then I can easily set the value of the local object to anything else.

Here's my code:

```
var myModule = (function(){
    var myLocalObj = {}; // I always get a warning in the IDE that this var is never read

    return{
        setObject:function(coll){
            this.myLocalObj = coll; // this works just fine
            this.myLocalObj.newProp = coll.prop // fails because 'myLocalObj' is undefined. 
        },
        getObject:function(coll){
           return this.myLocalObj;
        }
    };
})();

myModule.setObject(obj); // this is what I call after an ajax call is complete
```

Comment: Your IDE is correct. Please don't confuse variables with properties.

Comment: It seems like that's exactly what I'm doing. So if I want to set a local property and then get it later what is the best way to do it?

Comment: You'd use `return { myPropObj: {}, setObject: function(){ … this.myPropObj … }};`. Of course properties are never really "local", they are accessible to anyone who can access the object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `myLocalObj` isn't a property of the object returned, its a local var belonging to the scope. So, you can access directly using

```
setObject:function(coll){
    myLocalObj = coll; // be aware! you're overriding the original {}
    myLocalObj.newProp = coll.prop // now it works as expected
}
```

because the closure (setObject) has access to the scope variables.
You will need a getter as well to access the data from outside

```
getObject:function(){
    return myLocalObj;
}
```

Or if you need to keep safe the reference

```
getProp:function(prop){
    return myLocalObj[prop];
}
```

Hope you find it useful!

Answer (score 1):

I'll explain why these lines are doing what you're seeing:

```
this.myLocalObj = coll; // this works just fine
this.myLocalObj.newProp = coll.prop // fails because 'myLocalObj' is undefined.
```

`this.myLocalObj` is undefined.

So `undefined = 'some value'` is failing silently. So "this works just fine" is not true.

`this.myLocalObj.newProp` is the same as `undefined.newProp`.

`undefined` has no property, `newProp`, hence the error.

Of course I haven't tested any of that, just winging it, like every good programmer should! :D

Comment: I believe the first statement was working just fine because it feels like it was creating a new object and assigning an initial value. But the second statement fails because it can't create a new property at the same time it creates the new object.

Answer (score 1):

In you code, the *this* references the object returned. Therefore using *this* modifies the api and not myLocalObj. You might want to try something like this if you want the ability to assign the myLocalObj with something other than the empty object  that is already there.

```
    var improvedModule = (function(){
    var myLocalObj = {};

    var api = {
        init: function(obj) {
            if (obj) {
                myLocalObj = obj;//if this is not an object the api may break doing this!!!
            }
        },
        get: function(prop) {
            if (myLocalObj[prop]) {
                return myLocalObj[prop];
            }
        },
        set: function(prop, val) {
            myLocalObj[prop] = val;
        }
    };

    return api;
})();

improvedModule.init({
    foo: true,
    bar: false
});

console.log(improvedModule.get('foo'));
```

Comment: I thought that "this" references the "api" object that you noted above, not the function getting invoked.

Comment: You are correct, I mispoke, i will edit my answer, none the less, it does get you access to myLocalObj directly because it is in scope.